# Should original features be retained in the model after using them to engineer new features?

Tags: feature-engineering

**BACKGROUND:**  I have dataset that includes `Race` (e.g., White, Black) and `Ethnicity` (e.g., Hispanic, Non-Hispanic) as **observed variables**.  The dataset also includes `Race_Ethnicity` (e.g., Hispanic White, Non-Hispanic Black) as an **engineered variable**, if you will.  I am am wondering if I should retain the observed variables in my supervised ML model?

The observed variables are obviously correlated with the engineered variable.  This is an issue for ML (i.e., the multicollinearity problem), if I am thinking about this correctly (but please correct me if I'm wrong).  However, it may be possible that `Race` interacts with yet a 4th variable, whereas `Ethnicity` does not.  Thus, leaving out `Race` may be costing me important boost in performance.  (`Race_Ethnicity` may have a more "muddied" relationship with the 4th variable than `Race` alone.)

**QUESTION:**  What to do, y'all?  Should they (the observed variables) stay or should they go?

Comment: I would go with using the observed variables only. In that way, the model could draw and show, in its output, better relations between features, make possible better generalisations and be more interpretable. Adding the engineered ones will be just a nuisance.

Comment: @20roso, so the entire discipline of feature engineering is a waste?

Comment: In Feature engineering you do typically feature selection or feature extraction (e.g. PCA). In your case the features are concatenated, it's neither of both. In the same sense, why not concatenate all the features together and have just one? You get my point. Anyways, I told you my opinion, in the end you will be the judge, it's your dataset and you know it best.